# Getting issue while installing dependencies in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
neeraja@Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libgtkglext1-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev libpangomm-1.4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglibmm-2.4-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.61.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtkglext1-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libglu-dev
                    Depends: libgtk2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpango1.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpangox-1.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxmu-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgtkmm-2.4-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libatkmm-1.6-dev (>= 2.22.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libpangomm-1.4-dev : Depends: libcairomm-1.0-dev (>= 1.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497284/edit) to additionally show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Packages are built for a specific release; and you've not told us yours we can really only be generic (or advice already suggest such as checking your sources & output from `apt update`)